# Error when importing AngularFireDatabaseModule

Tags: angularfire

I'm trying to add angularfire database module to a new angular project but when i add the line :

```
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
```

i get this error :

```
Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/database/interfaces.d.ts:47:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'DatabaseSnapshotExists<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'DataSnapshot'.
  Types of property 'forEach' are incompatible.
    Type '(action: (a: DatabaseSnapshot<T>) => boolean) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(action: (a: DataSnapshot & { key: string; }) => boolean | void) => boolean'.
      Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
        Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
          Type 'DatabaseSnapshot<T>' is not assignable to type 'DataSnapshot & { key: string; }'.
            Type 'DatabaseSnapshotExists<T>' is not assignable to type 'DataSnapshot & { key: string; }'.  
              Type 'DatabaseSnapshotExists<T>' is not assignable to type 'DataSnapshot'.
                Types of property 'forEach' are incompatible.
                  Type '(action: (a: DatabaseSnapshot<T>) => boolean) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(action: (a: DataSnapshot & { key: string; }) => boolean | void) => boolean'.
                    Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
                      Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
                        Type 'DatabaseSnapshot<T>' is not assignable to type 'DataSnapshot & { key: string; }'.
                          Type 'DatabaseSnapshotDoesNotExist<T>' is not assignable to type 'DataSnapshot & 
{ key: string; }'.
                            Type 'DatabaseSnapshotDoesNotExist<T>' is not assignable to type '{ key: string; }'.
                              Types of property 'key' are incompatible.
                                Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
                                  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

47 export interface DatabaseSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.database.DataSnapshot {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/database/interfaces.d.ts:52:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'DatabaseSnapshotDoesNotExist<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'DataSnapshot'.
  Types of property 'forEach' are incompatible.
    Type '(action: (a: DatabaseSnapshot<T>) => boolean) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(action: (a: DataSnapshot & { key: string; }) => boolean | void) => boolean'.
      Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
        Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
          Type 'DatabaseSnapshot<T>' is not assignable to type 'DataSnapshot & { key: string; }'.
            Type 'DatabaseSnapshotDoesNotExist<T>' is not assignable to type 'DataSnapshot & { key: string; }'.
              Type 'DatabaseSnapshotDoesNotExist<T>' is not assignable to type 'DataSnapshot'.
                Types of property 'forEach' are incompatible.
                  Type '(action: (a: DatabaseSnapshot<T>) => boolean) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(action: (a: DataSnapshot & { key: string; }) => boolean | void) => boolean'.
                    Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
                      Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
                        Type 'DatabaseSnapshot<T>' is not assignable to type 'DataSnapshot & { key: string; }'.
                          Type 'DatabaseSnapshotExists<T>' is not assignable to type 'DataSnapshot & { key: string; }'.
                            Type 'DatabaseSnapshotExists<T>' is not assignable to type '{ key: string; }'.
                              Types of property 'key' are incompatible.
                                Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
                                  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

52 export interface DatabaseSnapshotDoesNotExist<T> extends firebase.database.DataSnapshot {
```

here's my complete app.module.ts file :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I already tried to delete and reinstall the package but that didn't work.
Also, i have an older project with exactly the same line of code and the same version of angular and angular/fire ("@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/fire": "^7.4.1") which work but i can't create a new one.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I had the same error with another error (Error TS2344: Type 'T[K]' does not satisfy the constraint).
And  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61735970/9560693) solved both

Comment: See this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188494/12349305

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Reason

The reason of this error is change of `forEach()` signature of firebase.database.DataSnapshot in firebase@9.9.2. Probably in your old project you have an older version (you can check in package-lock.json or in your node_modules) and the error will appear if you run `npm update --save` there.

These are interfaces from @angular/fire:

```
export interface DatabaseSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.database.DataSnapshot {
    exists(): true;
    val(): T;
    forEach(action: (a: DatabaseSnapshot<T>) => boolean): boolean;
}
export interface DatabaseSnapshotDoesNotExist<T> extends firebase.database.DataSnapshot {
    exists(): false;
    val(): null;
    forEach(action: (a: DatabaseSnapshot<T>) => boolean): boolean;
}
```

In firebase@9.9.2 firebase.database.DataSnapshot has such method:

```
forEach(
  action: (
    a: firebase.database.DataSnapshot & { key: string }
  ) => boolean | void
): boolean;
```

In firebase@9.9.1 it was:

```
forEach(
  action: (a: firebase.database.DataSnapshot) => boolean | void
): boolean;
```

## Solution

You can install firebase@9.9.1 explicitly to get rid of this error (`npm install firebase@9.9.1 --save --save-exact`). But remember to update it later when this issue is fixed: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3255

## Update

The problem is solved with firebase@9.9.3. `firebase.database.DataSnapshot` again has the same `forEach` signature as in firebase@9.9.1. So just use firebase@9.9.3 (or newer) or remove it from `package.json` and use version picked up by `@angular/fire`.

Answer (score 7):

Just open following file:

> **node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts**

You can see below that the subclasses have the wrong return value
[image]

Change it to this
[image]

Basically you just need to add `<T>` on the end.

Comment: Do not use pictures of text in questions or answers, they provide no value to visually impaired users, or users with image servers blocked. This answer also repeats a previous answer's (bad) advice to edit the vendor source files.

Comment: This is not the real solution to the problem. because as mentioned by @miken32 editing vendor source files doesn't work while deploying it to prod using CI/CD solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all the options I am getting, while older versions than 9.9.3 and the newer versions are also causing the same issue.

I have tried to skip the libCheck and it worked.

```
compilerOptions: { "skipLibCheck": true }
```

**Note:** This is obviously not a final solution but until the fix is released by Firebase we can use this tweak.

Answer (score 0):

I am Facing the same problem, so i back to the version **@9.9.1** the issue has been resolved after that, please enter the below code for resolving this issue-

```
npm install firebase@9.9.1 --save --save-exact
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error message after I updated lots of Node modules using `npm update`, including updating Firebase 9.9.4 to Firebase 9.10.0. Reverting to Firebase 9.9.1 didn't fix the problem. I reverted my project to the backup and updated the Node modules one by one, checking if Angular started up. The culprit turned out to be TypeScript, updated from 4.7.4 to 4.8.3. Staying with TypeScript 4.7.4 with project runs fine.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the interfaces.d.ts with this code, then i can get any collection from firestore.

```
export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<DocumentData> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
readonly exists: true;
data(options?: SnapshotOptions): any;
```

}

```
export interface DocumentSnapshotDoesNotExist extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
readonly exists: false;
data(options?: SnapshotOptions): undefined;
get(fieldPath: string | FieldPath, options?: SnapshotOptions): undefined;
```

}

```
export interface QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData> extends firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot {
data(options?: SnapshotOptions): any;
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade the typescript version to "~4.7.2" or less.

[image]

Install npm now.

```
npm i --force
```

Answer (score -1):

in the file interfaces.d.ts you might find errors on the lines with  add a "" at the end of each line before {

Answer (score -1):

In my tsconfig.app.json, I tried
compilerOptions: { "skipLibCheck": true }

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35345649)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

angular/fire 7.5.0 firebase 9.16.0
open the interfaces.d.ts the file that generates the error
add at the end of the row `<T>`

```
export interface QueryDocumentSnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>
```

Comment: Editing vendor source files is never the answer to a problem.