# Error @angular/fire build incorrectly extends interface

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angularfire

I start new Ionic/angular project and I add @angular/fire package.
When I run "ionic serve" I got these errors:

```
Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'DocumentSnapshotExists<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.
The types returned by 'data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData | undefined'.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {

node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:41
    13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.
node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:41
    13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData | undefined` constraint.


Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:23:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.
The types returned by 'data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

23 export interface QueryDocumentSnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot {

node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:23:40
    23 export interface QueryDocumentSnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot {
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.


Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:26:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'QuerySnapshot<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>'.
Types of property 'docs' are incompatible.
    Type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>[]' is not assignable to type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>[]'.
    Type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>' is not assignable to type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.
        The types returned by 'data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

26 export interface QuerySnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot {

node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:26:32
    26 export interface QuerySnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot {
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.


Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:29:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'DocumentChange<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'DocumentChange<DocumentData>'.
The types returned by 'doc.data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

29 export interface DocumentChange<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentChange {

node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:29:33
    29 export interface DocumentChange<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentChange {
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.
```

This is my configuration.
Package.json:

```
"@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
"@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/service-worker": "^15.0.0",
"@capacitor/app": "4.1.1",
"@capacitor/core": "4.6.1",
"@capacitor/haptics": "4.1.0",
"@capacitor/keyboard": "4.1.0",
"@capacitor/status-bar": "4.1.1",
"@ionic/angular": "^6.1.9",
"@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.1.1",
"ionicons": "^6.0.3",
"rxjs": "~7.5.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
```

Package-lock.json:

```
"node_modules/@angular/fire": {
  "version": "7.5.0",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "...
    "firebase": "^9.8.0",
    ...
  },

"node_modules/firebase": {
  "version": "9.15.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/firebase/-/firebase-9.15.0.tgz",
  ...
},
```

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireFunctionsModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any ideas to solve it?
I read similar problems but for older version, not for mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by change "node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts" following the instructions in [this link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3290#issuecomment-1323837275)

Comment: This is the  answer that you have been looking for, Rey. I can verify that it works! Probably as a quick fix

Comment: I don't want to ruin the fun but: LOL

Answer (score 16):

This solved my problem.

add the following in **tsconfig.json**

```
{ 
   "compilerOptions": { "skipLibCheck": true, } 
}
```

Comment: That's the way... thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to deploy the project to sites like Netlify. adding {"skipLibCheck": true } to compilerOptions in tsconfig.json is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Change this on

> node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts

```
export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
        readonly exists: true;
        data(options?: SnapshotOptions): T;
    }

export interface QueryDocumentSnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot {
    data(options?: SnapshotOptions): T;
}
export interface QuerySnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot {
    readonly docs: QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>[];
}
export interface DocumentChange<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentChange {
    readonly doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>;
}
```

to

```
export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot <T>{
    readonly exists: true;
    data(options?: SnapshotOptions): T;
}
export interface QueryDocumentSnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot <T>{
    data(options?: SnapshotOptions): T;
}
export interface QuerySnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot <T>{
    readonly docs: QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>[];
}
export interface DocumentChange<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentChange <T> {
    readonly doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's really ever a good reason to modify something in node_modules as a solution.  There are times when you have to remove/reinstall your node modules and this will be something you'll have to remember to do every time that happens.  Furthermore, any time you clone the repo (assuming it's in source control) you'll need to make this change.

Just not at all viable.

Comment: I don't want to ruin the fun but: LOL